# How to assign tasks to GPU and CPU Dask workers?

Tags: dask

I'm setting up a Dask script to be executed on PSC Bridges P100 GPU nodes. These nodes offer 2 GPUs and 32 CPU-cores. I would like to start CPU and GPU-based dask-workers.

The CPU workers will be started:

```
dask-worker --nprocs 1 --nthreads 1
```

while the GPU workers as:

```
CUDA_VISIBLE_DEVICE=0 dask-worker --nprocs 1 --nthreads 1
```

My workflow consists of a set of CPU only tasks and a set of GPU tasks, that depend on the results from the CPU tasks. Is there a way to bind a GPU task only to the GPU workers?

Furthermore, I would like to make sure that the GPU tasks land on the same compute node as the CPU task they depend on. Can I somehow do that?

Comment: I'm curious: Did you find a way?

Comment: I am curious to know how you ended up solving this problem

Answer (score 0):

For your sort of problem it makes sense to run `dask` using the `dask.distributed` backend (a more sophisticated task scheduler), which provides a functionality called **"worker resources"**.

For every worker it lets you specify virtual worker resources with an associated count, such as "GPU=2". On the client side you can then specify which and how many resources are required for each task. See the docs [here](https://distributed.dask.org/en/latest/resources.html).

For making sure a GPU task lands on the same compute node as the task it depends on you could:

- set the resources accordingly, i.e. splitting up tasks explicitly
  using resources like "GPU1" and "GPU2"
- alternatively, bundle the CPU and subsequent GPU task into one task either by manually defining an encompassing function or by using dask graph optimizations as documented [here](https://docs.dask.org/en/latest/optimize.html) (I'm thinking of "fusing" tasks).