# An example of workers with the right resource allocation in the dask distributed

Tags: dask, xgboost, dask-distributed

Does anyone have a working sample code that shows you can use CPU and GPU workers selectively with the `client.submit` api that dask distributed provides [here](https://distributed.dask.org/en/latest/resources.html#example)?

I am trying to train xgboost with dask-cudf in a distributed manner on GPU machines but I am not able to make it respects the resource tags I provide for different tasks

Comment: Can you share a [minimal version](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) of the code you are trying to run and be specific about the problem you are running into?

Comment: Take a look at this: https://stackoverflow.com/q/69215632/6701576
They also have some pseudo code but I am looking for a working version

Answer (score 0):

My friend and coworker, @pentschev (github), wanted to point you to this example from here:
https://github.com/dask/distributed/pull/4869#issue-909265778

```
import asyncio
import threading
import dask
from dask.distributed import Client, Scheduler, Worker
from distributed.threadpoolexecutor import ThreadPoolExecutor

def get_thread_name(prefix):
    return prefix + threading.current_thread().name

async def main():
    async with Scheduler() as s:
        async with Worker(
            s.address,
            nthreads=5,
            executor={
                "GPU": ThreadPoolExecutor(1, thread_name_prefix="Dask-GPU-Threads")
            },
            resources={"GPU": 1, "CPU": 4},
        ) as w:
            async with Client(s.address, asynchronous=True) as c:
                with dask.annotate(resources={"CPU": 1}, executor="default"):
                    print(await c.submit(get_thread_name, "CPU-"))
                with dask.annotate(resources={"GPU": 1}, executor="GPU"):
                    print(await c.submit(get_thread_name, "GPU-"))

if __name__ == "__main__":
    asyncio.get_event_loop().run_until_complete(main())
```

Output:

```
CPU-Dask-Default-Threads'-29802-2
GPU-Dask-GPU-Threads-29802-3
```